# How can I cover up bruises?

Tags: blood, treatment, injury

I have recently had a few bruises to my leg, one quite bad, I was just wondering is there any way of covering the bruises up? If so, how? What methods could I use?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Health SE! I am not sure your post is about health , but have you tried makeup or wearing pants until the bruises heal?